# WPF - How to make NVDA announce only the the number of items visible on screen?

Tags: wpf, accessibility, nvda

I’m having a WPF menu with 5 items, each with its own visibility condition. So sometimes, there will only be 2 items visible on the screen. However, in such case, NVDA still read “item 1 of 5, item 2 of 5”; basically, it still considers the menu to have 5 items.

Is there any way to make it read 2, or the number of item actually visible on the screen? Thanks.